# How to convert facebook user id (real id from v1.x) to scope user id (v2.x)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have users in database (holding facebook user-id from v1.x). And, I'm building a new application which uses facebook graph api v2.x

My problem is that old users can't login to the new application. I'm assuming that this is because the user id isn't a scope-id.

Any advices to allow old users to user my new application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New App means that users have to authorize it again, everything else would be weird and unsafe. Even if they would not have added app scoped IDs, you cannot just copy users over to a new App. But you can map users between different Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/